# iReport integration with extjs4.0.2a and Java + Spring + Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jasper-reports, extjs4

I am working on extjs 4.0.2a along with Java. I am using some framework with java such as Hibernate/JPA and Spring. Now I want to use a Jasper Report designing tool i.e. iReport to generate my reports in different formats (.xls,.pdf) etc. I am familiar with iReport. I generated the iReport file in .jrxml and .jasper format using the jdbc connection.

Now i want to integrate my generated report with JAVA so I can get the report in either .pdf or .xls format. When I click on pdf icon I can download the report generated in .pdf format.

I am using Ext js 4.0.2a mvc architecture. Anyone having idea how to proceed can help me

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365045/spring-mvc-3-0-jasper-reports-4-directing-html-reports-in-browser & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567660/inetgrating-ireportwith-large-no-of-sub-reports-with-spring-mvc & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239838/whats-the-best-way-to-show-html-reports-generated-by-jasperreport-in-a-jsp

Comment: Another link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446666/how-to-set-up-jasper-reports-in-spring-with-subreports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for this problem is simple. As you are using ExtJs I think your controller is in JavaScript.

1. Do a request for the java server to create your report in pdf, xls, whatever
2. Save the report in your session with a key(can be the time in mileseconds)
3. Return the key to the view and open a new window to ask the server for your report

The new windows should contain a URL like this `http://localhost:8080/myApplication/report?key=312312313`

If you want to download to xsl you can try this:

```
private void exportToExcel(HttpServletResponse resp, JasperPrint jasperPrint) throws IOException {
    String reportfilename = tagreport("file") + "repor.xls";
    JExcelApiExporter exporterXLS = new JExcelApiExporter();

    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT,jasperPrint);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE,Boolean.TRUE);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, resp.getOutputStream());
    resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename="+ reportfilename);
    resp.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    try {
        exporterXLS.exportReport();
    } catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Henrique I am able to generate my xls report using jasper report. Now when i click the export button I am able to generate the excel report file. But I am not able to download it. I am making server request to generate report using **Ext.Ajax.request({
 url: 'task/GetTaskReportPDF.action'})** on tomcat console in header i am getting **ontent-Disposition attachment
Content-Length 0
Content-Type application/vnd.ms-excel
Date Fri, 20 Jan 2012 10:00:49 GMT
Server Apache-Coyote/1.1** so what i am doing wrong that doesn't allow the download popup to come. .

Comment: thanks Henrique it works. Now i want the same download window for my pdf report genrated. I made the changes as **JRPdfExporter exporterPDF = new JRPdfExporter();           exporterPDF.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperprint);           exporterPDF.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, response.getOutputStream());
           response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename="+ reportfileName);           response.setContentType("application/pdf");exporterPDF.exportReport();** but it doesn't give me download window to save or open the pdf report generated

Comment: Sorry, you are using the stackoverflow a bit wrong. You should now choose your answer and make a new question. Is a different problem now

Comment: hi.. henrique i posted the new thread you can go to my question by clicking the link **[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951786/pdf-download-dialog-window-not-appear-in-browser-extjs-4-with-java)**. if you had any solution related to it, so i can solve it.